# OWL 2.2.0 Is it possible to see only the item active center and hide slides before and after?

Tags: hide, slide, owl-carousel

2.0 and I would like to see only one slide which is the class: "owl-item active center"
Could you help me?
thank you and have a good day

Comment: Please can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) illustrating the problem you experience.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery script :

```
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

        $(".owl-carousel").each(function(index, el) {
            var containerHeight = $(el).height();
            $(el).find("img").each(function (index, img) {
                var w = $(img).prop('naturalWidth');
                var h = $(img).prop('naturalHeight');
                $(img).css({
                    'width': Math.round(containerHeight * w / h) + 'px',
                    'height': containerHeight + 'px'
                });
            })
        });

        // Carousel initialization
        owl.owlCarousel({
            center: true,
            loop:false,
            margin:0,
            singleItem:true,
            autoWidth: true,
            navSpeed:500,
            nav:true,
            autoplay: false,
            rewind: true,
            items:1
        });**strong text**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JRG6.jpg)

Comment: <code>CSS style 


    .owl-item {
        display: table;
    }

    .owl-carousel .item {
        height: 80vh;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }</code>